# {Spoiler} AOT - When exactly did Eren get Attack and Founding titan from his father?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So in finale Eren says that he directed the titan towards his mother because Bertolt was there and he still was important for things. (So that he survives and Armin takes his power and not some random eldian).

So I understand the context that the time is all at once for Eren / Founding Titan, and not a linear passage which human brain is used to.

So for this logic to work, in Eren's own POV - he has to be actually already in power of both attack and founding titan from his father on the day of attack, before the attack happens.

As per the anime although it comes across as that happens later in the day post the attack, because he doesn't have the key AFAIK when the attack takes place and post the jungle conversation with his father he has the key of the basement thereafter. So this is when gets founding titan and attack titan and this is post initial attack - after the wife/mother is dead.

So two things here,

1. Even if time is all at once for him and he is literally jumping from one frame to another - therefore when he gets the founding titan he is able to see that memory. But how is he directing that titan to go towards the mother, unless he is travelling in time and can be at any place at any time and it is not dependent on character's own frame reference. For example let's say I have founding titan power, so for me past - present - future is all at once and not in a linear way - but it's my timeline - my POV. Or is it like, I can traverse time and be anywhere in the world, even though me in normal time space haven't gone through that experience. (Am I clear here? In short, am I looking at different time frames based on my POV or I am full on time traveller with independent mode of thinking and travel post founding titan power).
2. Or the founding titan is a complete master of time who can create own branches of time like sandbox of present and run scenarios at parallel and therefore when Eren gets the power he travels back in time sees everything through in one of the sandboxes and chooses to go ahead with the one where he likes the whole plot. - As it seems he did run sandboxes where he explains this was the best outcome possible and he did consider other possibilities. Even eren spending time with Mikasa in the woods, that scene. If master of time logic is not true which I hope it isn't then he was just spending time with her and erasing her memory like he was doing with multiple others.

My current understanding is founding titan's power allows you to draw memories of everyone who have had the power or will have the power so it's more like memory traversal for founding titan. So more like I can traverse through memory of my past, present and future and all - reincarnations (reincarnations of founding titan). If that's the case confusion still remains.

1. When did Eren get titans from Grisha. And how is Eren explaining him sending titan towards his mother - please corelate that.

Just a sidenote all the time references that has been shown primarily in the anime - Founding titan's own POV only is referenced and nothing else.

EDIT

Only acceptable explanation in my head is - that eren gets founding titan's capabilities later so now he can travel across his POV, now based on that he redirects titan towards his mother but even then we are not shown Bertolt near that titan who eats eren's mother in episode 1. So when did in Eren's POV this scene even happen because that's not shown to us. He runs towards the house, they are near his mother and then that titan is running towards them. Now only possible answer is Bertolt is standing there in the side lines while Eren is being carried off by Hannes and that's when redirects the Titan towards his mother.

Answer (score 1):

He got his powers the day/week before the wall fell when he ate his dad who had just eaten the Founding Titan and killed the royal family.

I guess that it was when he was older when his head got shot off, not when he first touched Historia that he set his plans in motion. Going back to when the wall first fell as a child, adult Eren was hiding subconsciously telling the Titans what to do.

Comment: I believe Grisha transfers the powers of the Attack/Founding Titan to Eren after Wall Maria falls not before. The reason he wasn't in Shiganshina during the fall of Wall Maria was because he was off at the Reiss chapel begging them to act to save those about to die. Failing to convince them he steals the Founding titan and returns to find Eren among the refugees and turn over both titans